# Error sintáctico en CSS

Tags: css

Estoy teniendo problemas para ubicar  como una sidebar en mi página web. Puse a prueba la hoja de css con la que estoy trabajando y me resulta en un error sintáctico, pero no estoy pudiendo identificar de qué se trata.

¿Me ayudarían a encontrarlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: te sobran varios }

Comment: te sobran y te faltan }

Comment: Te hago una aclaración, en CSS abres un { y lo cierras. No pueden haber llaves intercaladas. Además el código **siempre** va como texto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es el siguiente:

Imagina que tienes la siguiente estructura en *HTML*.

```
<section>
    <h1>Título</h1>
    
    <p class='parrafo'>Parrafo 1.</p>
    <p class='parrafo'>Parrafo 2.</p>
    <p class='parrafo'>Parrafo 3.</p>

    <article>
        <p class='parrafo'>Parrafo article 1.</p>
        <p class='parrafo'>Parrafo article 2.</p>
        <p class='parrafo'>Parrafo article 3.</p>
    </article>
</section>
```

Ahora vamos a decorarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
section {
    width: 50%;
    background: #CCC;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.parrafo {
    color: #006699;
}
```

Donde quiero que pongas atención es en la clase **parrafo**, cuando lo usas de esta forma aplicas el color de texto a todas las **p** que tienen la clase **parrafo**. Ahora bien si yo quiero acceder solo a los párrafos del **article** que tengan la clase **parrafo** lo haré de la siguiente forma:

```
article .parrafo {
    color: #006699;
}
```

Y bueno a lo que quiero llegar con esto es que tu error es hacer ésta operación de la siguiente forma:

```
article {
    .parrafo {
        color: #006699;
    }
}
```

Cosa que o bien simplemente no funcionará o te mostrará un error como el que recibes. Espero te sirva saludos ;)

> Ah y solo una sugerencia más **indentar tu código** no estaría demás para detectar estos errores de forma más sencilla e incluso evitarlos.

Comment: A lo mejor quiso usar SCSS no? Por eso la forma en que cierra y abre las llaves

Comment: Si también se me ocurrio eso después jeje, de todas formas su archivo dice *styles.css*